# Join a domain from inside a Hyper-V guest OS

Tags: domain-name-system, hyper-v, domain-controller

I have a Windows Server 2008 inside Hyper-V.

My host OS is a Domain Controller.

I can ping my network from the guest OS, but I can't join the domain. It gives a DNS error:

> The operation returned because the timeout period expired.

Could anyone help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely the cause of your problem is that your guest OS DNS settings isn't set to HOST OS IP. Point your Guest OS DNS settings to HOST OS IP and it should start working. Other then that you should be aware that HOST OS running Hyper-V role isn't supposed to run anything else on it except the Hyper-V role. So  I would suggest to move Active Directory Role out of Hyper-V host.,

Comment: Umm... yeah... how could you have a domain controller without having a DNS server?

Comment: o_O what... I don't even.

Comment: @joeqwerty installer gives you an option to skip dns setup

Comment: MadBoy: AD requires a DNS server that supports SRV records. It sounded to me like the OP didn't have a DNS server at all, which prompted me to wonder how he has an AD domain without a proper DNS server.

Answer (score 1):

This is becoming a bit of a catchphrase for me when advising people on troublshooting problems like this, but here goes:

> The important thing to remember about virtualisation when solving
>   problems like this is that nothing magical happens to your network,
>   good or bad, just because someone took a network diagram and said "by
>   the way, these hosts are now virtual".

I'm assuming you've set up the HyperV server properly, tested that can talk to the network happily in itself, and installed the guest in line with best practices, including installing the Integration Services.
So assuming all that, how would you troubleshoot this if the guest machine wasn't virtual at all?

- You'd check that the ip addresses and in particular the DNS setting are set correctly
- you'd check that the server could ping the workstation
- You'd check name resolution (e.g. can the client ping itself by name, is the client in DNS, can you run NSlookup and resolve server names...)
- You'd check the firewall on the client (and any that might be *between* the client and the server) are not filtering traffic
- You might try seeing if you can connect to a share on a server over SMB...

Answer (score 0):

If it were simply a matter of not having the the ip address of the AD\DNS server set in the TCP/IP properties of the client you'd be getting an error of the likes of "a domain controller could not be found for the specified domain". Because you're getting a timeout error I suspect a network or firewall issue. Check the firewall on both the guest and host, then check to make sure you have network connectivity between the guest and host.